# Columns in PHP: Third column skipped, but all data from DB are there

Tags: php, mysql, sql, echo

So I have weird issue here. All datas are correctly called from database, but when I want to echo it third column in table is skipped. I noticed that if I delete column `Datum` everything is fine.

```
function KupljeneUlaznice() {
    $KupljeneUlaznice = KupljenaUlaznica::retrieve_all();
    $ret = [];
    foreach ($KupljeneUlaznice as $KupljenaUlaznica) {
        if ($KupljenaUlaznica->Korisnik()->Email == $this->Email) {
            array_push($ret, $KupljenaUlaznica);
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

function Korisnik() {
    $br = new Korisnici;
    $br->retrieve($this->Email);
    return $br;
}
```

---

And this is how it looks when I want to echo it:

```
$ul = $kor->KupljeneUlaznice();
        echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
                <tr id="htablica">
                    <td>Broj ulaznice</td>
                    <td>Datum</td>
                    <td>Tip ulaznice</td>
                    <td>Jed. cijena u €</td>
                    <td>Količina</td>
                    <td>Način plaćanja</td>
                    <td>Ukupna cijena u €</td>
                </tr>';
        foreach ($ul as $u) {
            echo '<tr>

                <td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->BrojUlaznice . '</td>
                <td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->Datum.'<td>
                <td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->Ulaznica()->NazivUlaznice.'</td>
                <td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->Ulaznica()->CijenaUlaznice.'</td>
                <td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->Kolicina.'</td>
                <td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->NacinPlacanja.'</td>
                <td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->UkupnaCijena.'</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

---

This is final result: http://i58.tinypic.com/2wfso48.png

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close your <td> tag on the "Datum" column:

```
<td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->Datum.'<td>
```

Should be:

```
<td class="sadrzaj">'. $u->Datum.'</td>
```

Note the </td> at the end instead of <td>

Comment: Unbelievable that I didn't see it! Thank you for finding out about that little mistake :) It's obviously working now